# Output alternate field in case bound field is null on a Kendo MVC Grid ClientTemplate

Tags: vb.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a cell in a kendo MVC grid that I'd like to take one of two data fields depending on the value of one:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Of RTFVM)().Name("RealTimeFinancials") _
 .Columns(Sub(c)
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.LineItem).HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "text-align:left"})
                  c.Bound(Function(x) x.Line.Months(0).Total).Format("0:#,##0}").ClientTemplate("#if(data.Line.Months[0].Message == null) {data.Line.Months[0].Total} else {data.Line.Months[0].Message} #")

          End Sub) _
```

etc

The cell is rendering as blank every time regardless of the result of the null comparison.  I must be missing something obvious!

Comment: Have you tried removing `data.` from your properties in the ClientTemplate?

Comment: Kendo MVC seems to use the 'data' object when referencing the model schema (can be seen when looking at the generated JS produced by the mvc wrapper).  CodingWithSpikes answer below seems to work too using 'data'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#...#` template markup just executes JS but does not output anything.

Instead, try `#:...#` or `#=...#` which both output a value back to the HTML, or this template:

```
#if(data.Line.Months[0].Message == null) {##:data.Line.Months[0].Total##} else {##:data.Line.Months[0].Message##}#
```

(it looks weird on 1 line, but if you were to insert line breaks it would make more sense:)

```
#if(data.Line.Months[0].Message == null) {#
  #:data.Line.Months[0].Total#
#} else {#
  #:data.Line.Months[0].Message#
#}#
```

I think this template might also work:

```
#: data.Line.Months[0].Message ?? data.Line.Months[0].Total #
```

Which would use the null-coalescing operator to use `Total` in the case where `Message` is falsey.

Comment: Superb!  Works perfectly, thank you.  I'd struggled to understand what the difference between #, #= and #: was.

Comment: For future reference, the difference between the 3 is documented here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#template-syntax